# I can't scroll far enough down the screen in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scrollview

I'm making my own android application, working in Eclipse using Java, and I got 1 buttons inside. Every button has is own information inside. Some of those buttons involve so much text, that a scrollview is added. However, in this particular button, I can't scroll down to the bottom completely. It scrolls down to a certain part, but it leaves out a hyperlink and one more sentence with text, that is not visible this way.

This is an image from my page, with the yellow light on the bottom, showing that it's not able to scroll down further than it is on the image. There is still text, with a hyperlink under it, but I can't scroll down to that

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLpoE.jpg)

This is my main code

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RouteActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route);

        findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_route);
        text += "<a href='https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Plein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden/@52.4594977,4.6245747,18.5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!2sPlein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden!3b1!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212!3m4!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212'> Klik daarvoor op deze link</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent intent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {



            case R.id.button11:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/RKZ.BrandwondencentrumBeverwijk");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                break;
            case R.id.button12:
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/user/rodekruisziekenhuis/featured");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/rodekruiszh?lang=nl");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
                break;
            case R.id.button14:
                Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com/company/rode-kruis-ziekenhuis");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                intent = new Intent(RouteActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Route" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_route"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my strings.xml code where I code the text inside. The button to look at, is the `<string name="title_activity_route">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Rodekruis</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main"></string>
    <string name="title_activity_nieuws"><b>Nieuws</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Volg de ontwikkelingen in en om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis op onze website, hier is een internetverbinding voor nodig. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/nieuws_agenda_nieuws'> </a>
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_afspraak"><b>Afspraak</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Maken en wijzigen</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Zelf uw afspraak maken of wijzigen? Dat kan, mits us al als patiënt geregistreerd staat bij het RKZ. Is dit nog niet het geval? Dan wordt de afspraak telefonisch gepland. Meer info&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Bekijk ook</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022 </string>  
    <string name="title_activity_bezoek"><b>Bezoektijden</b>\n\nVrijwel iedere patiënt vindt het prettig bezoek te ontvangen. Onze ervaring is
    dat een goed contact met vrienden en familie een bijdrage kan leveren aan 
    een spoedig herstel.\n\nVoor de meeste afdelingen gelden de volgende bezoektijden:\nvan 15.15 tot 16.15 uur;\nvan 19.00 tot 20.00 uur.\n\nLet op: tijdens feestdagen gelden in het RKZ andere bezoektijden dan normaal. Bekijk de website voor uitgebreide bezoektijden.
</string><string name="title_activity_contact">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Contact</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Telefoon en internet Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5555 (algemeen nummer, ook Poli IJmuiden)&lt;br /&gt;www.rkz.nl<a href="https://www.rkz.nl"> </a>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Huisartsenpost Midden-Kennemerland (begane grond RKZ)&lt;br /&gt;Voor huisartsenzorg buiten kantooruren&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5265&lt;br /&gt;
    (A.u.b. bellen voordat u langskomt)&lt;br /&gt; Spoedeisende Hulp RKZ en Huisartsenpost: meer informatie&lt;br /&gt;Bij levensbedreigende klachten belt u altijd 112&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bezoek- en postadres Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;Route(link)&lt;br /&gt;Postbus 1074&lt;br /&gt;1940 EB Beverwijk
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_mening"><b>Uw mening</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Uw mening is voor het RKZ erg belangrijk. Graag horen we wat er goed gaat, wat beter kan en wat absoluut beter moet. Daarmee werken wij weer verder aan betere kwaliteit van zorg en patiëntenveiligheid.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U kunt <br>uw mening</br> op verschillende manieren geven:&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</string>
    <string name="title_activity_route">\n\n\n\n<b>Route</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis, hoofdgebouw&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;De Velsertunnel is van medio mei tot eind 2016 gesloten.&lt;br /&gt;Voor verkeer vanuit zuidelijke richting is het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk hierdoor moeilijker bereikbaar. Bekijk: &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie korte routes naar/van het RKZ&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie langere routers naar/van het RKZ&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    plan uw route naar/van het RKZ met      actuele verkeersinformatie&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;RKZ Poli IJmuiden (tijdelijk i.v.m. sluiting Velsertunnel)\nGezondheidscentrum Het Plein&lt;br /&gt;Plein 1945, nr.105&lt;br /&gt;IJmuiden&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Plan uw route <a href='https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Plein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden/@52.4594977,4.6245747,18.5z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!2sPlein+1945+105,+1971+GC+IJmuiden!3b1!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212!3m4!1s0x47c5f0342468ea39:0xf05b19898f4b29!8m2!3d52.4593706!4d4.6246212'> </a>&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Meer informatie over de Poli IJmuiden</string>
    <string name="title_activity_specialisten"><b>Specialisten</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis vindt u beknopte informatie over al onze specialisten. Om deze informatie te raadplegen heeft u een internetverbinding nodig. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U kunt in het specialistenoverzicht zoeken op achternaam of op specialisme. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/specialisten_en_behandelaren/?group=rks'> </a></string>
    <string name="title_activity_bwc">  &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Brandwondencentrum</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Het RKZ Brandwondencentrum, beter bekend als: Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk, levert al meer dan veertig jaar topklinische zorg op het gebied van huid-, brandwonden- en littekenbehandelingen en wordt zowel in het binnen- als buitenland hoog gewaardeerd.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Wie werken er in het Brandwondencentrum? Wat maakt het centrum zo bijzonder? Wat is een brandwond precies, wanneer is behandeling in het Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk nodig? Welke behandelingen vinden er plaats? Hoe vindt een opname plaats en wat zijn de bezoekregels? En welke afdelingen en poliklinieken behoren tot het brandwondencentrum?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van Brandwondencentrum worden deze vragen uitegebreid beantwoord.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk heeft speciaal voor kinderen en tieners een <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> </a>
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_agenda">AgendaActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_informatie">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Welkom op de RKZ app!</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U heeft de app gedownload van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk. Met onze app geven wij u beknopte, praktische informatie over ons ziekenhuis die u deels offline (zonder internet) kunt raadplegen.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Voor vervolginformatie verwijzen wij u via links naar onze website. Hiervoor heeft u internet nodig.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bent u in het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis, dan kunt u gebruik maken van gratis Wifi (draadloos internet). Hoe werkt het?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   Ga naar de WiFi-instellingen op uw mobiele apparaat.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   Maak verbinding met het netwerk <b>RKZ_Bezoekers.</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Open uw internetbrowser (zoals Internet, Explorer, Firefox of Safari)&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   U komt automatisch op de portal van het RKZ. Wilt u gebruik maken van Wifi in het RKZ, dan klikt u hier op <u>akkoord</u> om de voorwaarden te accepteren.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   De browser verwijst u door naar de pagina http://www.rkz.nl.</string>
    <string name="title_activity_vriend">\n\n\n\n<b>Word vriend van het RKZ</b>\n\nEen verblijf in het ziekenhuis is meestal niet erg plezierig. De Stichting Vrienden van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis spant zich in om het verblijf van patiënten, bezoekers en medewerkers van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis en het bijbehorende Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk te veraangenamen. Door geld in te zamelen voor voorzieningen die niet uit het basisbudget van het ziekenhuis kunnen worden betaald. Denk aan een opknapbeurt voor de speelkamer voor jonge patiënten of een verwenbehandeling bij een chemokuur.\n\nOok u kunt helpen. Door Vriend te worden van het RKZ of door ons eenmalig te steunen. Lees verder op de website.\n\nMet vrienden om je heen voel je je beter. Geef om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis. 
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_folders"><b>Folders</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis kunt u folders downloaden over ziektebeelden, behandelingen en onderzoeken. Hiervoor heeft u een internetverbinding nodig.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;U kunt zoeken op trefwoord of op alfabet. <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/overzicht'> </a> 
</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Apply padding bottom in your scrollView

Comment: did u solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ScrollView then always use `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above` attributes. Don't hardcore the height of the scrollview.Check the code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Route" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
         android:layout_below="@+id/fl1"
         android:layout_above="@+id/llbutton"
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_route"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy textView(empty with transparent background) below your ScrollVIew textview and give its height = the height of your hidden text. You can put a relative/linear layout inside your scrollview and put the two textviews inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I got simmilar problem and this helped me:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/messages_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/send_panel"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/messages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView Here>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This seems to work, only my bottom 4  buttons, Facebook, Youtube, Twitter and Linkedin or gone now. Those are on the complete bottom of the page

Comment: i think if u will modulate this code everything will be work fine, u need try this on any others ways

Comment: i got this issue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT-jlwMhWiA
and with code on my answer i resolve it

Comment: But with those 4 buttons under the scrollview code, you don't know how to solve that? The scroll function works fine now, just the 4 buttons are under the page and not visible

Comment: maybe make them in new LinearLayout?

Comment: are u trying to make this
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Route" >
a relative?